# parse error with Knockout and templates

Tags: knockout.js

I have my template included like so although I get an error in the browser, shown below.  If I move the input and button outside the template it works although I don't understand why.  Can anyone advice as I'm fairly new to knockout.  Thanks,

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'keyword-template', data: Article }"></div>
```

The template has the following mark up.

**Update**

```
<script type="text/html" id="keyword-template"> 
  <div> 

    <table class="KeywordList" data-bind="foreach: Keywords">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: $data">
      </td>
      <td data-bind="click: $root.delete">
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <input data-bind="value: toAdd" />
    <button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>     

  </div>                              
</script>
```

When running this code in the browser I get the following error

**Error**

Error: Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: add is not defined;
Bindings value:     click: add
Source File: /js/libs/knockout-2.2.0.js
Line: 57

**Update: Javascript included**

```
window.helper = {
Start: function (tagging) {
  var viewModel = helper.viewModel(tagging);
  window.helper.ViewModel = viewModel;

  viewModel.keywords = ko.observableArray(viewModel.Keywords().split('|'));
  viewModel.toAdd = ko.observable();
  viewModel.add = function () {
    viewModel.keywords.push(viewModel.toAdd());
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are including all the Javascript, but the viewmodel should have an add function in it to call, and that is what the error is showing:

```
function Article() {
    var self = this;
    self.Title = ko.observable();
    self.Body = ko.observable();

    self.add = function() {
        // do what is required for the add function here
    };
}
```

Or if your add event is a level above this viewmodel then you need to change your button to:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this template is used inside a foreach loop, yet the "add" function is defined in the root of your view model?  Inside a "foreach" binding, the context of data-binding is the individual element being iterated over.  You'll need to bind to either "$parent.add" or even "$root.add".

See the [Knockout documentation on the binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) for more information.

Comment: You are binding your view to your view model so you need to include add and the other functions inside of your view model